# Python - Pandas - Printing String Attributes of Two Columns

Tags: python, pandas

This works if I want to print substring of one column:

```
print(myDf["thisCol"].str[:2])
```

But, if I want to substring another column and include it in the output, I'm not sure how to do this.

Contrived output of above is roughly:

```
0 fo
1 ba
```

What i want, with the second column being say "anotherCol" where the maximum length is greater than 2, is the output:

```
0 fo    tr
1 ba    ca
```

(Disclaimer: I couldn't find the answer with multiple searches. And I'm learning Pandas in a sort of sideways fashion....)

Comment: Where does the second column come from? Can you provide a [mcve] with some copy-pastable data please?

Comment: Second column is the same dataFrame.  This works, but is not what I want as I have to add my own spaces between the columns: print(myDf["thisCol"].str[:2]+"     "+myDf["anotherCol"].str[:2])  Thanks, btw!

Comment: Fantastic, but what is `myDf["thisCol"]`? I would like to see the data that produces your contrived output. Also, what should "anotherCol" contain and how is it initialised?

Comment: The data is all string. I just used example data above sorry. Complete strings would just be longer in some cases. Eg. foo, bar, hi_, tree, cat, sun

Comment: I'm sure what I wan to do is simple and I am probably going about it in the wrong way.... basically I just want to be able to truncate some of the columns that I print. :)

Comment: And sorry, my second output above should just have two rows, not three. Note:  I edited question above to be correct.

Comment: If you provide a sample column coldspeed or anyone else will be able to help you easily!

Comment: Does `myDf['thisCol'].str[:2].str.cat(myDf['thatCol'].str[:2], sep=' ')` work?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a factor, which represents the number of spaces desired, to multiply it to a single space in the `print` statement

```
import pandas as pd

# mock data following your example, replace by your own data
col1 = ['foo', 'bar']
col2 = ['tri', 'car']
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'this_col': col1, 'another_col': col2})

# Specify your desired number of spaces between the dataframe columns print
desired_num_spaces = 10

# Print dataframes with specified columns separated by the desired number of spaces
print(my_df['this_col'].str[:2] + desired_num_spaces * ' ' + my_df['another_col'].str[:2])
```

gives

```
0    fo          tr
1    ba          ca
dtype: object
```

Btw: In Python the use of snake_case for variable and key names is preferred. Please do not use camelCase naming style as used in other languages like C#, Java, ...

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['foo','bar'],'col2':['foo','bar'],'col3':['foo','bar']})
```

Select the required columns and then apply the ***chooper*** function, which will cut the string upto first two characters

```
def chopper(x):
    return x[:2]

print(df[['col1','col3']].applymap(chopper))
```

Output:

```
  col1 col3
0   fo   fo
1   ba   ba
```

Another option:

If your threshold for substring is 5 or more, you can use pandas display options

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',6)

pd.set_option('max_colwidth',6)
df=pd.DataFrame({0:['asdfzklnlkdsfnalsdfknals;dknfs','asdfs0'],1:['foo','bar'],2:['foo','bar']})
print(df)
```

output:

```
      0    1    2
0  as...  foo  foo
1  as...  bar  bar
```